# How to load data from Local storage... I tried many things but nothing works

Tags: swift, uiimage

Ho to show the image from below url
URL->

file:///Users//Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F4A0B7EA-292B-4DFC-B6A0-8AE0DD80BBD1/data/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0005.JPG

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? You cannot load resources from arbitrary system locations... If you try to just load an image from the user's photo library there are apis that facilitate that by prompting for the necessary permissions.

Comment: How did the image get there in the first place? How did you obtain the url? And what are the many things you've tried?

Comment: obtaining this from url?.absoluteString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to get url-

```
var paths: [Any] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, 
.userDomainMask, true)
let documentsDir: String? = (paths[0] as? String)
let url: String = documentsDir! + "/IMG_0005.JPG"
```

Comment: can u tell me how to load image from this url?

Comment: let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: url)